Maven Swagger Codegen Plugin Issues with Dependencies
I have a Spring Boot project that is using swagger-codegen-maven-plugin to generate client code from a Swagger 2.0 spec. The project is using Java 21 and Spring Boot 3.2.4.
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.39</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-spec</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/swagger-spec.json</inputSpec>
                <language>java</language>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>

The code generation works fine and the code is generated under /target/generated-sources/swagger as expected.
However, how do I use this generated code? Don't I need to install the generated client to include it as a dependency in the main project?
Right now it is just included as a source directory, and of course it is missing the dependencies specified in the generated pom file.

Hi Conner, what do you mean with "how do I use"? Do you need to use it on an IDE in the main project (which is the only project that also generate swagger spec), or as a library?

@Cavva79 Yes, it is being generated by the project that is going to use the generated code. My expectation, though, was for the maven artifact to be installed to the local repository so it can be used by the main project. Right now, it just dumps the generated code into /target/. Is there a way to have it be installed after it is generated?

If you want to install generated code to local repository you should create a maven submodule or a brand new maven project with only the "generator" and pack it in jar. Then you can import as a dependency in the main project

@Cavva79 How would the submodule work though? How do I mark the generated code as a submodule to be installed by Maven? Can maven handle submodules in the /target/ directory?

have you understood how to do it?

@Cavva79 nope! I haven't been able to look into it.

Sorry to the late answer, you have to split your project in 3 pom, first is the main with packaging pom, with 2 modules one is your application and the other is the openapi/swagger-spec library. The application must import the library dependency. Is it clear? If you use eclipse as a IDE you have to add build-helper-maven-plugin if   m2e.version to import  ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/main/java as java source code
